# How To Use Triggers to insert Changes in MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

i want to create triggers and i have a requirement to do the following.

When a record in a tables is edited trigger that will automatically log this change to another table called  logs and where it use  inside my  php script 
 The set up of the log table will be as follows:

date
time
value before
value after 
edited table
* i am  new for  triggers  please help me my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your google-fu is weak my friend: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html but you will learn eventually :)

Though if this is not a project dedicated to creating triggers, I would not advice to use them. Since this " that will automatically log this change to another table called " can surely be done in business logic. Then you can control what is done from software and by the user. Maybe in the near future you will need to perform a datafix on your table - then you would have to disable the trigger, perform the fix and enable it again. That seem like a lot of work you don't really want to do.
So if possible - avoid triggers, if not - read the mysql docs on how to create them.